# About “the level of perception”

Tags: expressions

If we talk about a performance that does not reconstruct historical background but is supposed to appeal to our feelings omitting all formal evidences, can we use the expression *on the level of perception*? Like *The city and village in the performance are read out on the level of perception* (meaning that there are no houses, cars, trees and so on).

Comment: No - your construction is effectively "meaningless" in English (presumably it's some kind of literal translation of a usage which would be easily understood in your native tongue). You probably want something like ***superficially***, but your use of ***are read out*** here doesn't sound at all "natural" either. Perhaps ***superficially sketched in***.

Comment: I mean some inner details that help us understand that it is a village, so I don't like the word “superficially”, while it is about outward characteristics. Can I say “are read out intuitively”?

Comment: ***No!!!*** - You definitely *can't* use "intuitively" here! I think your preconceptions about "superficially" are misguided, but if you don't like that, maybe you should think about a different way of phrasing things.

Answer (score 2):

Perception is not correct here because it does nothing to exclude concrete, physical things at all. You can perceive houses and cars as much as you can perceive emotions, or perhaps even more. It sounds like you're looking for a way to describe something that conveys an impression without all the details.

*She read out an **impression** of the city.*

*It described the city **abstractly***.

*They captured the **essence** of the city*

*The play conveyed the city's **character*** (or soul/spirit)

*We expressed the **zeitgeist** of the town*

*He described the city on an **emotional** level*

"Are read out" is somewhat unclear. I recommend writing, "He read out," "It described," or anything that specifies who or what is reading.

Answer (score 1):

Your case seems pretty nuanced and I'm not sure exactly what you're going for here. You seem to be talking about an abstract description that evokes a visceral understanding. I don't know of any idiomatic way to express that but 'level of perception' is not something that would be commonly understood by English speakers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely certain what "read out" means in the original sentence. My impression of the overall question, though, is that you want to say that a play (or something similar) was performed without a set, or with a very sparse set, yet the performance still evoked a sense of place. That is probably how I would say it, too: "Despite the sparse sets, the performance *evoked* a strong sense of place and time."

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be trying to avoid a negative connotation, I can see why you wouldn't like superficially. Some synonyms could maybe work better with some slight restructuring of the sentence.

*"In the performance, the city and village portray the times **cosmetically**"* may get you what you need.

Comment: How does “cosmetically” express my idia if it's just opposite? I try to say that there is no visual evidences, that it's all about feelings.

Comment: @BukvaCe I did not understand that's what you were going for. You could replace **cosmetically** with **emotionally** in my sentence to convey that.